Lower bound needed for two independent trials have small difference
Suppose I have a probabilistic experiment that i know that follows $Bernoulli(p)$, but don't know the exact value of $p$. So I conduct two experiments to find out the value of $p$. The exact formulation is the following:
Let $X_i, Y_i\sim Bernoulli(p)$, and I do $N$ trials for each experiment, i.e find out both $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_{N}$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_N$. After then, I observe the results, and find out
$\hat{p}_1=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ and $\hat{p}_2=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NY_i$. As these are random experiments, after $N$ trials of the experiment, we can't have an exact guarantee that $\hat{p}_1=\hat{p}_2$. Yet, I do want to have some faith in this experiment, so I want to have $|\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2|\leq \epsilon$, so that I can believe in the data, and say that $p\approx \hat{p}_1\approx \hat{p}_2$. I have two questions.

Is this hypothesis reasonable? Of course there are some cases such that $|\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2|\leq \epsilon$ yet $p\neq \hat{p}_1\approx \hat{p}_2$. I want to know whether this case happens a lot(as $N$ goes to infinity).

Is there a lower or upper bound in the value of $N$ that ensures that $|\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2|\leq \epsilon$ is satisfied? An obvious lower bound is $1/\epsilon$, but I can't go any further



For any finite $N$, you cannot guarantee $|\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2|\leq \epsilon$ even if ${p}_1={p}_2$ so you need to say with what maximum probability you want this to not happen to determine $N$; this is related to $\alpha$ the rate of false positives (Type I errors) and the size of the test.  Having done that, you can look at the rate of false negatives (Type II errors) $\beta$ or the power of a test if the true difference is some given small non-zero amount $\delta$.  One approach is to decide $\alpha, \beta, \delta$ and use these to determine $N$ and $\epsilon$.

@Henry Thank you for your kind answer. Can you elaborate how to determine $N$ and $\epsilon$ from $\alpha, \beta, \delta$? I have never heard about these type I and II error, and I don't know a lot about statistical hypothesis testing.

@Henry Moreover, I thought about it a little bit more, and isn't $|\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2|\leq \epsilon$ guaranteed by WLLN? I can't grasp the reason why we can't guarantee $|\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2|\leq \epsilon$ for given $\epsilon$.

To take an extreme example, if you have $n$ samples from each, then the probability $\mathbb P(|\hat p_1 -\hat p_2|=1) = p_1^n(1-p_2)^n+(1-p_1)^np_2^n$ which is positive no matter how large $n$ is, and then there is more probability the difference is between $\epsilon$ and $1$.  So there can be no guarantee.  If $p_1=p_2$ then $\mathbb P(|\hat p_1 -\hat p_2| >\epsilon) \to 0$ as $n$ increases by the WLLN even though the probability is always positive.
